# how to receive input data from muiltiple <form> to a single action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my MVC Razor view I have a partial view with `<form>` tag in it. I need to add another partial view in main view. As `<form>` is in 1st partial, I m not able to get input data from 2nd partial in action. Can you please suggest how I can get input data from 2nd partial view to action without client side manuplation (Java Script/ JQuery usage) ?

Comment: Partials can include/render other partials. Is there anything preventing you from doing that?

Comment: Rowan Freeman, layout of page is that reason.

Answer (score 3):

That will be the natural issue with the setup you have.  Consider first not putting any form in the first partial, and keep the forms only within the main view.  Then render the partials in the main view within the form... a push in the direction of a web forms setup, but it would work...

It's very easy for me to say this, but without seeing your code, I can't provide anything concrete.